# Davening with an Egalitarian Minyan

Tags: halacha, tefilla, heterodox

I will be participating on a summer program this summer with egalitarian davening, including women leading, laining, having aliyot, etc. Can I respond amen to their brachot? Can I respond to their kedushah? To their aliyot? If I was a gabbay, could I call up a girl? I cannot think of other questions that might come up, but if anyone can think of other issues please add them.

Comment: Shira Chadasha in Jerusalem identifies itself as an Orthodox egalitarian minyan.  When I visited there women led parts of the service (not the t'fillah, but e.g. p'sukei d'zimra) and had aliyot, and there was a bat mitzvah the week I was there.  I once had a link to the halachic sources they base their practice on but I can't find it now; maybe this comment will help somebody else.  (Oh and yes the men said "amen" and otherwise fully participated.)

Comment: http://www.ou.org/index.php/jewish_action/article/28208/

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is dealing with the group's definition of what counts as a minyan/quorum. For example, a nice (and real) question is what would you do if Halacha/your psak says that there is nowhere close to a minyan but at some important point the group holds that there is exactly a minyan with your presence.

Even without having a role, you can't always be a neutral observer.

Comment: Great question and I'm still not sure how I'd deal with this situation

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe said to distance oneself from such minyanim ([OC 4 91:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=177)).

Comment: Sounds like extremely good advice to me.

Comment: Sam, the teshuva advises distancing from "kofrim".  From what Monica cited, these congregants seem to be believing Jews, but quite liberal and nontraditional in their practices.  While R' Moshe may consider them part of his second group mentioned and one should not daven with them or give any impression of such, there is no indication of him advising distance.

Comment: @YDK I was under the impression that it was not orthodox Jews ,and one does have to daven in a different place even if it is the second type. Regarding protesting such a thing is dependent on the circumstances as is written.

Comment: I see that Sean's question cites "leading" and "leining" as opposed to, say, getting an aliya.  So I suppose you are correct that they would not even affiliate with orthodoxy.  Either way, the answer davening with them is clearly no from R' Moshe's teshuva.

Comment: @YDK - I can do whatever I want and call myself Orthodox. I believe that Chizkiyahu was a Mashiach, so does that make me Christian? They can call themselves Orthodox if they want to. And how do you know that Rav Moshe felt that these people in particular were heretics?

Comment: @Aman - Maybe, if you particularly enjoy burning bridges.

Comment: @adam mosheh so does Rav Hillel but we have the Ramabams Ikkarim.

Comment: @sam - Ra'avad was not Orthodox?

Comment: @adam mosheh not sure what you are saying?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, its a free country!

Comment: @sam - Ra'avad was Orthodox but he disagreed with Rambam all over the board including the 13 Ikkarim. Shulchan Aruch disagrees with Rambam as well.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I'm not afraid of offending people if there happen to be problems, or things I am convinced are problems.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Henkin permitted davening in a shul without a mechitza under limited circumstances. He [writes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22080&st=&pgnum=28):

"Every individual should live in a place of observant Jews if
possible. However, if this is not possible, we should not be strict
concerning these matters because it will lead to a potential
catastrophe.

However, if the place itself is corrupt in that it has mixed-seating,
it has already been established that it is preferable to pray by
yourself at home. But, if this is the only synagogue in the area and
you will always have to pray at home, you must examine the situation
and evaluate the corruption versus the hope that through the
involvement of the observant in this congregation, the community will
become Orthodox. Yet, in all situations you must reprimand them if you
pray in their midst."

I'm not sure how this ruling would apply to the summer program you are participating in, since R. Henkin was talking about only mixed seating, but not necessarily mixed participation, but some of the factors to consider are mentioned in his response.

Comment: Thank you, that is some food for thought. Does anyone have any more thoughts regarding saying amen, participating in kedushah, etc?

Comment: -1, mixed participation does not necessitate mixed seating or lack of mechitzah.